# Имитировать форму поиска

Tags: html, css, форма

Не могу имитировать форму поиска. То-есть визуально это должно отображаться как форма поиска "Search" но при клике на нее пользователь переходит на страницу (соответственно урл страницы прописывается в коде).
Нужно чтобы:

1. Отображалась надпись "Поиск по сайту;
2. Отображалось изображение "лупа";
3. Сама форма как ссылка на страницу;

Повторяюсь это имитация поиска, визуально это форма поиска в ней **НЕ должен набираться текст**. Просто при нажатии переход на станицу. То-есть пользователь видит и думает, что это форма поиска, но по факту это ссылка.
Кого не затруднит накидайте плиз код и CSS. Очень буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете просто взять абсолютно любую форму поиска и наложить на неё через `display:absolute` свою ссылку. 
Вот как пример:

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend+Deca|Dosis&display=swap");
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 16px;
        flex: 1;
        background: #d86f06;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
        overflow-Y: none !important;
    }

    button img {
        transition: transform .25s;
    }

    button:hover > img {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    button:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    input {
        font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    }

    input::placeholder {
        font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
    }

    input:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    .href {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
       width: 100%;
        margin-top: -3%;
        height: 30%;
    }

    .searchbox {
        height: 60px;
        width: 450px;
        max-width: 100%;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 50px;
        display: flex;
    }

    .searchbox > .btn-menu {
        padding: 16px;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .searchbox > .search {
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .searchbox > .btn-search {
        padding: 16px;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .search-modal-header h3 {
        font-size: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 500;
        float: left;
    }

    .search-modal-header span img {
        float: right;
        position: absolute;
        right: 16px;
        top: 25px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: .5s all;
    }

    .search-modal-header span img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    .search-modal-body .message {
        display: flex;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .search-modal-body .message-avatar {
        margin-right: 16px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .search-modal-body .message-avatar img {
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        object-fit: cover;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    }

    .search-modal-body .message-body {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .search-modal-body .message-body p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #444;
    }

    .search-modal-body .message-body small {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-family: Dosis;
        color: #777;
    }

    .search-modal-body .message:hover {
        background-color: #2F94D817;
    }
    @keyframes slideInUp {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 15%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 15%, 0);
            visibility: visible;
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="searchbox">
    <button class="btn-menu">

    </button>
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" name="search" class="search">
    <button  class="btn-search">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/24/000000/search--v2.png">
    </button>
</div>
<a href="https://google.com" class="href"></a>
```

Comment: @Denis640KbБлагодарю что откликнулись. Это не то. Такое я пробовал. Повторяюсь это имитация поиска, визуально это форма поиска в ней НЕ должен набираться текст. Просто при нажатии переход на станицу. То-есть пользователь видит и думает, что это форма поиска, но по факту это ссылка.

Comment: @Denis640KbПроблема, у меня на вордпресс в этой "форме" набирается текст. Эта якобы форма будет отображаться под каждым постом, при клике на которую (форму) переход на заданную станицу

Comment: @Budun Всё что Вам нужно - это задать позиционирование элемента так, чтобы он находился на поле ввода.

Comment: Какого элемента? Что не пробую не работает.

Comment: @Budun Стиль `.href`

Comment: @Budun Удалось подставить?

Comment: Вы предложили такой гигантский код CSS. Как я понимаю, можно в DIV заключить 2 класса и минимум CSS. Вот не получается ни как так сделать....  блин хоть бери картинку формы прописывай. Но ведь хочется на HTML.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104759/discussion-between-denis640kb-and-budun).

Comment: Ну так заходите в чат.